# ViewBag value returning wrong number

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to insert values from `ViewBag` into an input through javascript and dynamically creating the value.

I call the value of `employeeID` that is made with the controller

```
public string GetEmployeeID(out string idMethod)
{
        string ee_Id = string.Empty;
        ClientEmployeeSetupDefaults ee_Setup = this.dbContext.ClientEmployeeSetupDefaults.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClientID == GlobalVariables.Client);
        string nextIdSuffix = string.Empty;
        idMethod = ee_Setup.EmployeeIDMethod;
        switch (idMethod)
        {
            case IDMethod.Sequence:
                ee_Id = NextEmployeeID(ee_Setup.EmployeeIDNext, "", out nextIdSuffix);
                break;
            case IDMethod.PrefixPlusSeq:
                ee_Id = NextEmployeeID(ee_Setup.EmployeeIDNext, ee_Setup.EmployeeIDPrefix, out nextIdSuffix);
                break;
        }
        if (nextIdSuffix != string.Empty)
        {
            ee_Setup.EmployeeIDNext = nextIdSuffix;
            this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        return ee_Id;
}
```

with the ViewBag

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "CreateProcess";
string employeeID = @ViewBag.EmployeeID.ToString();
var LoginCode = @ViewBag.LoginCode;
}
```

Its inserted with the javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    alert('doc ready happened ' + @employeeID + ' - ' + @LoginCode);
    document.getElementById('LoginCode').value = @LoginCode;
    document.getElementById('EmployeeIDs').value = @employeeID.ToString();

});
</script>
```

I have debugged all the way through and each time on an employeeID of `010015001` it returns `2103809` regardless if it pulls from the database dynamically or if i hardcode the value.

During this process it also runs through this method

```
public ActionResult CreateProcess(string d, string p, string e, string c, string pp)
    {
        string method;
        List<Id_Name> Profiles = GetAvailableProfiles(p, d);
        ViewBag.Profiles = Profiles;
        ViewBag.LoginCode = GetLoginCode();
        string eeID = GetEmployeeID(out method);
        ViewBag.EmployeeID = eeID.ToString();
        ViewBag.IDMethod = method;
        ViewBag.SelectedDepartment = d;
        ViewBag.SelectedPosition = p;
        ViewBag.SelectedEEClass = c;
        ViewBag.SelectedEStatus = e;
        ViewBag.DefaultProfile = Profiles[0].ID;
        xxx.SignOn = this.dbContext.xxx.Where(obpt => obpt.TaskType == xxx.SignOn && obpt.SetupID == Profiles[0].ID).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.SignOnTask = SignOn.TaskID;
        return View();
    }
```

I can't figure out why it would return that random number and why through all of debugging it shows the correct `010015001` but on refresh it loads in the bad number.

Comment: You should me using a model not viewbag for this data.

Answer (score 2):

Integers with leading zero are in octal (base 8) notation.

010015001 (octal) = 2103809 (decimal)

If your `employeeID` string contains an integer number in decimal form, you should strip the leading zero:

```
string employeeID = @ViewBag.EmployeeID.ToString().TrimStart(new char[]{'0'});
```

Comment: Thanks Igor. THis is helpful, but sometimes the ID has to start with a 0.

Comment: Then set it as a string, i.e. `document.getElementById('EmployeeIDs').value = '@employeeID.ToString()';`. Notice the quotes around the Razor value.

Comment: @Igor: Very nice catch.

Comment: @TheDizzle - ah, if `employeeID` is always treated as string, then Chris' suggestion should solve your problem, since it avoids the conversion to integer.